# golang simplejson mustint64 doesn't convert from string to int64

Tags: go, casting, simplejson

I am using simplejson, and it provides type asserters.

```
fmt.Printf("%s %s", m.Get("created_time").MustString(), m.Get("created_time").MustInt64())
```

above code shows this result:

```
1506259900 %!s(int64=0)
```

So MustInt64() gives 0 instead of converted Int64 value.

Is it because the 1506259900 is too big to be converted?

Thank for your help!

Comment: I don't think `simplejson` converts a json string value to an `int64` with `MustInt64`. Can you provide the json you're trying to parse?

Comment: Yes I found the reason, you're definitely right.

Answer (score 0):

The original json was:

```
{"created_time":"1505733738"}
```

Not

```
{"created_time":1505733738}
```

It's originally a STRING, not a NUMBER.

So, when use MustInt64() to that json, it should return 0 because type is not matched.

Right way to treat this is using strconv.

```
i64, err := strconv.ParseInt(m.Get("created_time").MustString(), 10, 64)
```

And you'll get what you wanted as i64.